# How to get the property name when using a for...in loop

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

```
const dog = {
   id:1,
   name : "Henry",
   breed: "border-collie"
}

   for(let prop in dog){
      if(prop.name === id && typeof prop === "number"){
          console.log("this prop is ok!")
          continue
      }
      if(prop.name === name && prop === "Henry"){
          console.log("prop is ok!")
          continue
      }
      if(prop.name === breed && prop === "border-collie"){
          console.log("mucho bueno")
          continue
      }
      else{
        console.warn("prop could not be identified") 
        break
      }
   }
```

So what I have here is some code which is correct, I believe, except for the `.name` pseudo property. I want to cycle through the whole list of a dog's properties, but I also want to be able to check the names each of the dog's properties to make sure they are valid.

is there a way to do this in a for...in loop. if not, what else can I do in order to be able to cycle through the props and check the prop name?

Comment: `prop` *is* the property name. Where you’re using `prop`, you should be using `dog[prop]`.

Comment: This is kind of a strange question. Do you really need to check that all dogs are border-collies named Henry. Will you have other dogs of different breeds and names? If so, the `if/then`s will get out of hand. There are some nice ways to validate, but it's not clear *what* you will be validating. Is there a list of valid dog names?

Answer (score 1):

`prop` is already the property name, as a string; the value would be `dog[prop]`.

```
const dog = {
    id: 1,
    name: "Henry",
    breed: "border-collie"
}

for (let prop in dog) {
    if (prop === "id" && typeof dog[prop] === "number") {
        console.log("this prop is ok!")
        continue
    }
    if (prop === "name" && dog[prop] === "Henry") {
        console.log("prop is ok!")
        continue
    }
    if (prop === "breed" && dog[prop] === "border-collie") {
        console.log("mucho bueno")
        continue
    } else {
        console.warn("prop could not be identified") 
        break
    }
}
```

You can also use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to iterate over keys and values as pairs:

```
for (let [name, value] of Object.entries(dog)) {
    if (name === "id" && typeof value === "number") {
        console.log("this prop is ok!")
    } else if (name === "name" && value === "Henry") {
        console.log("prop is ok!")
    } else if (name === "breed" && value === "border-collie") {
        console.log("mucho bueno")
    } else {
        console.warn("prop could not be identified") 
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (key in dog)
```

This iterates the keys (id, name, breed).

Corresponding values will be dog[key].

Comment: This is going to loop over a bunch of numbers now, and create a global `key` (or fail in strict mode).